# Percentage issue, getting an element to follow 100% browser width

Tags: html, css

I have been working on a mobile version ov my webpage for a while now, playing around with various media queries and solutions. However I seem to have put myself at a miss. I was resizing elements to take 100% of the browser width when a device with a screen width of 800px or less is detected.

All of my other elements have fallen into place, except for one, and I have spent two days looking for the fix. I assumed it was a set width I had set somewhere in the Css but after copious searching I havent found any. The accordion navigation element seen in the middle of this webage, **[(My Webpage)](http://www.scandalband.co.uk/mobile.html)** Is suppoosed to span the width of the page but instead is massive surpassing the border of the webpage.

I would be greatly appreciative if I could get a fresh set of eyes to see if I have made a mistake here.

The main CSS area I belive to be the problematic area.
(styles.css) & (accord.css)

```
#wrapper {
width:100%;
}
#wrapper #c-wrap{
width:100%;
position: relative;
}

.ac-wrap-m{
width:100%;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-bottom: 1em;
position:relative;
}
```

I took the page from the desktop build and remastered it and I know I did use set widths in the desktop build. Thats the only thing I think the problem could be, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Best seen if you resize the browser window down to around 800px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

div #c-wrap has a set width of 1000px and #wrapper has a min-width of 1080px. Once you remove those and change them to something else. you will not see the horizontal scrollbar

Comment: Yeah I was going to had to wait 2 minutes though. :P

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
min-width: 100%;
```

To your #wrapper #c-wrap code inside your media query and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Added this code still no progress. it still surpasses the browser window. :(

Comment: This code was needed in the #wrapper Css aswell. Which I added. I cant upvote yet, but when I can I will return to upvote your answer as it did aid the question. Thanks again!